# Developer account was blocked

Tags: developer

my developer account was blocked because of some reset security token wrong attempts.As per forgot password option,i got mail like bellow...

[image]

i tried the mail as per given mail id...but do not response from there.....

so what can i do to enable my account and start my work

please help me.....

Comment: Your account maybe temporarily disabled and come back to life after 15mins (dependent on your security settings). Otherwise just create a new org and migrate your setup into there - you can have as many developer orgs as you need.

Comment: thanks for replay...yesterday that was blocked...right now it is not opened...there are many important things in my developer org..so right now i am not thinking for new org.....

Comment: hint: create multiple admin users with your own email on developer accounts you really can't afford to lose.

Comment: I ran into this issue too... and lost my developer org from it.  In order for it to be opened, they ask for a signature from a CIO or equivalent in your company.  It's extremely stupid because I locked myself out of my personal dev org and that's what they asked of me.

Answer (score -2):

Contact your org administrator and ask for a **Reset Password**. It's under **Setup -> Manage Users -> Users**. Click on required User and click on **Reset Password**

UPDATE : Check the ideaExchange [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bDrMAAU) as well. This may help you.

Comment: thanks for response,but i am admin of my developer account..right now it's not opened so how can i go for setup->manage Users....that's the problem here....

Comment: Doh! See my update as well if it'll help you