# Deploy Apex Classes, Visualforce pages, Triggers and Components to Developer Org

Tags: deployment, eclipse, workbench

My developer Account was blocked due to some kind of wrong attempts(that was happened while sync with eclipse) and here is the link that was posted by me some time ago still not solved.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/31483/5483

i have one folder of class,triggers,static resources,vf pages and apex classes.so here i want to deploy in my another developer account.i was tried workbench and eclipse but gives some kind of error.

here i attach some kind of snapshot for your reference please refer it

[image]
[image]

So basically **what can i do to deploy that kind of folder in the new org**?

want some your reply and thanks in advance.

Comment: P.S. Did you email "support@salesforce.com" to try and get your password reset?

Comment: ya i was sent many mail on support regarding password reset but there is no replay from there

Comment: what error did you get ?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the Force.com IDE or the Migration Tool.

### Force.com IDE

Right-click on your project, choose Force.com > Deploy to Server..., and follow the prompts. It will complain about not being able to synchronize your code, because you're locked out of your current developer edition, but this won't stop the IDE from deploying to the new organization.

### Migration Tool

Set up an appropriate target in your build.xml, then deploy to the new server. Build.xml should be placed in the FirstSalesforce folder (not the src folder), and your target would look like this:

```
<target name="deploy">
    <sf:deploy username="mynewdev@someorg.com" password="thesecretword" deployRoot="src" serverurl="https://login.salesforce.com" />
</target>
```

Use the "sample" project file that's included with the Migration Tool to get started. You can download the Migration Tool from Setup > Develop > Tools. You'll also need to install Apache Ant if you choose this route.

Comment: You could run into issues if you have created custum fields or objects which seems not to be part of your eclipse project. If @sfdcfox way does not work, please tell us the exact error message you get.

Answer (score 1):

If you get stuck with with the tools depending on how many classes, pages, etc. you have a manual recreation could be possible. Therfore you should start with fields and objects if you custumized thoses and are using them in your code. Unfortunately objects are not in what you have as backup. So if you later cant save due to missing fields, you need to manually recreate them first.

Continue with the classes and create each of them one after the other with the same name as in your backup but empty and paste the contents from your local files into it. You may have to do it in the right order if one class is using an other the other one have to be created first. Then you can go on with static resources, pages, triggers, etc.

Will cost some time, but I think you will be able to restore a lot.

But if the deployment as @sfdcfox mentioned works, it would be way better.